# Kotlin recursive problem when type checking

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following code which i think is valid, because the recursion happens as a result of a callback. It's not called directly as a result of the function call. But the compiler seems to think there is a recursion issue

```kotlin
class Model(callBack: CallBack) {
    interface CallBack {
        fun onSomething()
    }
}

class SomeClass {
   fun createModel() = Model(callBack)
        
   val callBack = object : Model.CallBack {    
        override fun onSomething() {
            val anotherModel = createModel()
            // Use model for something
        }
   }
}
```

```
Type checking has run into a recursive problem. Easiest workaround: specify types of your declarations explicitly
```

Is there a workaround for this?

**EDIT**

I also tried changing `callBack` to a function so that the same instance is not referenced by multiple models, but I get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive problem mentioned is not about function calls, it's about the compiler trying to find out the types of the declaration and it has stuck in a recursive type checking. It wants to find the output type of `createModel` which depends on the type of `val callback` and it depends on `createModel` again. As it says, declare their types to fix the issue.

```
class Model(callBack: CallBack) 
{
    interface CallBack {
        fun onSomething()
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    fun createModel() : Model = Model(callBack)
        
   val callBack : Model.CallBack = object : Model.CallBack {    
        override fun onSomething() {
            val anotherModel : Model = createModel()
            // Use model for something
        }
   }
}
```